# How do I make the countdown display in a countdown timer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Python and just programming in general. I need help to create a countdown display to my timer which is a tequila timer. My friends drink a lot of Tequila and asked me to make them a timer, because they know nothing about computers.

Anyways, I have made the layout the best way I could do it and it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvt57.png

What I need help with is that when the 1 minute button is clicked, it counts down from one minute to 0. And the same goes with the other button. I also need help with the stop ruction, so you can stop the timer at any time by pressing the stop button. It would really be a big help!!

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

#GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tequila timer")

#Load of background with the tequila bottle
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=423, height=700)
canvas.pack()
Load = tk.PhotoImage(file="tequila.png")
canvas.create_image(211, 350, image=Load)

#buttons
btn_1min = tk.Button(root, text="1 min", width=10, height=5, command=root.quit)
btn_1min_v = canvas.create_window(140, 350, window=btn_1min)

btn_10min = tk.Button(root, text="10 min", width=10, height=5, command=root.quit)
bt1_10min_v = canvas.create_window(283, 350, window=btn_10min)

btn_1hour = tk.Button(root, text="1 hour", width=10, height=5, command=root.quit)
bt1_1hour_v = canvas.create_window(140, 475, window=btn_1hour)

btn_2hours = tk.Button(root, text="2 hours", width=10, height=5, command=root.quit)
bt1_2hours_v = canvas.create_window(283, 475, window=btn_2hours)

btn_stop = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", width=10, height=5, command=root.quit)
bt1_stop_v = canvas.create_window(211, 600, window=btn_stop)

#Display
label = tk.Label(root, text="00:00:00", width=9, font=("calibri", 40, "bold"))
label.pack()
label_v = canvas.create_window(211, 200, window=label)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is none of your buttons are mapped to anything. Well, other than `root.quit` which just closes your window.

So lets start with your first problem. You need to update the text in your `Label`. A good way to do that is with `tkinter`s `StringVar` class. Updating a `StringVar` will also update the text in your `Label` so lets do that first.

```
countdown = tk.StringVar()
countdown.set("00:00:00")
```

and then set it as the text in your `Label`.

```
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=countdown, width=9, font=("calibri", 40, "bold"))
```

Now that that's taken care of. lets move on to your second problem. Your lack of call back functions. First lets set us up with a function to call that accepts a variable amount of seconds to count down from.

To display something after `root.mainloop()` has been called we can use the `after()` method. It will return an identifier that we can use to cancel the update later. However, in order to use it in another function later to cancel, we should make it a global variable with the keyword `global`.

The `root.after` takes a milliseconds argument and a function to call after those milliseconds have elapsed. Lets call this function again with one fewer milliseconds than it was called with. also, if the seconds have dipped below 0 we should cancel the callback.

We can do that with `root.after_cancel` and handing it the `after` identifier we retrieved from `root.after` before.

Another thing to note is that `root.after`s function argument expects a function object. To hand it a function with an argument we can wrap it in a lambda.

```
def update(seconds):
    global after
    if seconds >= 0:
        countdown.set(seconds_to_time(seconds))
        after = root.after(1000, lambda: update(seconds - 1))
    else:
        root.after_cancel(after)
```

But what is this `seconds_to_time` function were setting our `StringVar` to? Well, it's just a little helper to make our seconds display in a proper `hh:mm:ss` format.

```
def seconds_to_time(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds -= hours * 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds -= minutes * 60
    return f'{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}'
```

And your final request is to stop the countdown. We can do that by just cancelling our global after identifier. It's a good idea to make sure we've set the after first by avoiding `NameError` errors in case it hasn't been set yet.

```
def stop():
    try:
        root.after_cancel(after)
    except NameError:
        pass
```

Full code below:
note the callback functions for your buttons are wrapped in lambdas to allow us to hand an argument to the callback.

```
import tkinter as tk

def update(seconds):
    global after
    if seconds >= 0:
        countdown.set(seconds_to_time(seconds))
        after = root.after(1000, lambda: update(seconds - 1))
    else:
        root.after_cancel(after)

def seconds_to_time(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds -= hours * 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds -= minutes * 60
    return f'{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}'

def stop():
    try:
        root.after_cancel(after)
    except NameError:
        pass


#GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tequila timer")

#Load of background with the tequila bottle
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=423, height=700)
canvas.pack()
Load = tk.PhotoImage(file="tequila.png")
canvas.create_image(211, 350, image=Load)

countdown = tk.StringVar()
countdown.set("00:00:00")

#buttons
btn_1min = tk.Button(root, text="1 min", width=10, height=5, command=lambda: update(60))
btn_1min_v = canvas.create_window(140, 350, window=btn_1min)

btn_10min = tk.Button(root, text="10 min", width=10, height=5, command=lambda: update(600))
bt1_10min_v = canvas.create_window(283, 350, window=btn_10min)

btn_1hour = tk.Button(root, text="1 hour", width=10, height=5, command=lambda: update(3600))
bt1_1hour_v = canvas.create_window(140, 475, window=btn_1hour)

btn_2hours = tk.Button(root, text="2 hours", width=10, height=5, command=lambda: update(7200))
bt1_2hours_v = canvas.create_window(283, 475, window=btn_2hours)

btn_stop = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", width=10, height=5, command=stop)
bt1_stop_v = canvas.create_window(211, 600, window=btn_stop)

#Display
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=countdown, width=9, font=("calibri", 40, "bold"))
label.pack()
label_v = canvas.create_window(211, 200, window=label)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just have two questions more if that's not a big problem? By the way, thank you for your great commentry! It really helps when you're a newbie like me! :D                                               My questions are is it possible for the counter to say Tequila after its done with eg. a minute and then resets it when you click on eg. 10 min? Is it also possible to get it to play an audio file when the counter ends at zero? :D